# ¿Cómo hago para pasar esta query de PL/SQL a JSON?

Tags: funciones, plsql, oracle-18c

Trate de distintas formas y no logro ,por favor necesito ayuda

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE retemp AS OBJECT (
      employee_id NUMBER,
      phone_number VARCHAR2(2000)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE colretemp AS TABLE OF retemp;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getempxdept (
      dept IN employees.department_id%TYPE
) RETURN colretemp AS
    emp1 colretemp := colretemp();
BEGIN
     SELECT
           retemp(e.employee_id, e.phone_number)
     BULK COLLECT
     INTO emp1
     FROM
         employees e
     WHERE
         departament_id = dept;
     RETURN emp1;
END getempxdept;
```